# Jquery: Smooth Scrolling script not working

Tags: jquery, href, smooth-scrolling

Somehow I can't figure out how to make this Smooth Scrolling Jquery script work for me.

The first console.log does returns "Test", the second one returns nothing after I click on a link. I'm working on Localhost through Prepros, might this have something to do with the script not working? Also the code doesn't return any errors.

[jQuery Code Snippets: Smooth Scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

`<script src="scripts/dist/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>`

```
var local = local || {};
local.Link = (function() {
var link = {};

console.log("Test");

function linkSmoothScroll() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {

        console.log("Test-inside");
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $(this.hash);
            $target = $target.length ? $target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');

            if ($target.length) {
                var baseMinScrollTime = 200,
                    baseMaxScrollTime = 500;

                var docHeight = $(document).height(),
                    triggerTop = $(this).offset().top,
                    targetTop = $target.offset().top;

                var scrollProportion = (targetTop - triggerTop) / docHeight,
                    relativeTime = ((baseMaxScrollTime - baseMinScrollTime) * scrollProportion) + baseMinScrollTime,
                    // Create inverse relationship (quicker the further we scroll)
                    scrollTime = -1 * (1 - relativeTime);

                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: targetTop - 10
                }, scrollTime);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

linkSmoothScroll();

return self;

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by animating the scroll and using an additional CSS property.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0" }



html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```